# Azure Cloud Service does not pass runtime environment variables to startup tasks

Tags: azure, cmd, environment-variables, startup, azure-cloud-services

I have created a Cloud Services definition with several start-up tasks. I have a common set of Environment variables that I want to be available from each task, for example if it's running in the emulator. For that I used the the following documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/cloud-services-startup-tasks-common/#differentiate-between-running-in-the-emulator-and-the-cloud

The problem is that I do not get any variables from the runtime block passed into my tasks. Any variables declared at the task level are passed normally.

My definition looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="Portal.CloudService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
    <WebRole name="Portal" vmsize="Small">
        ...
        <LocalResources>
            <LocalStorage name="StartupLog" sizeInMB="100" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false"/>
        </LocalResources>
        <Runtime>
            <Environment>
                <Variable name="ComputeEmulatorRunning">
                    <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/Deployment/@emulated" />
                </Variable>
                <Variable name="CurrentEnvironment">
                    <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/ConfigurationSettings/ConfigurationSetting[@name='Environment']/@value" />
                </Variable>
                <Variable name="StartupLogPath">
                    <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/LocalResources/LocalResource[@name='StartupLog']/@path" />
                </Variable>
                <Variable name="testvar" value="test"/>
            </Environment>
        </Runtime>
        <Startup>
            <Task commandLine="AddCertToTrustedRootCA.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
            <Task commandLine="ConfigureIIS.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple">
                <Environment>
                    <Variable name="taskvar" value="test"/>
                </Environment>
            </Task>
        </Startup>
        ...
        </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

I'm debugging `ConfigureIIS.cmd` at the moment. I get passed the `%taskvar%`-variable defined at task level, but the runtime variable `%testvar%` is not available, like all the other runtime environment variables.

What I have tried so far:

- Set only the most simple variable (`%testvar%`) and remove the `RoleInstanceValue` variables
- Set the `<Runtime>`-element to `<Runtime executionContext="elevated">` to match the tasks execution level
- Remove the `executionContext` from the tasks

As far as I can see my code is equal to the example as given by Microsoft and yet it does not work. Did I make a mistake in my definitions, or am I missing something?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue. At this point I have to assume the MS example is incorrect. I believe runtime variables can be used in the code but you have to declare them in each task section if you also want to access them there

Comment: No, I haven't figured it out. I came to the same conclusion you have. Eventually I wrote a single startup task batch file, which in turn calls other tasks. This way I only have to declare the Environment variables for the the single task.